# Multiple selects within one query - one based on another

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'd like to return multiple result sets from a single query with an assumption that the second select is based on first. Basically I need to return:

Table1

ID, Name

Table2

ID, Name, Value, Table1ID

I think joining those tables wouldn't be the case as Table2 may contain several items for the same row from Table1.

Is there any efficient and performance-wise way to do that? Maybe using CTE?

@EDIT

Sample Data:

```
Table 1:
ID    Name
1     First
2     Second

Table 2:
ID    Value    Table1ID
1     2,25     1
2     2,45     1
3     1,94     2
4     2,12     3
```

And the result I need is data set (I use C#, so I'll use C# "syntax" here)

```
DataSet.Tables(0)
    ID    Name
    1     First
    2     Second

DataSet.Tables(1)
    ID    Value    Table1ID
    1     2,25     1
    2     2,45     1
    3     1,94     2
```

I will have to combine those two tables later on as my class related to Table1 contains list of values. I'm wondering whether I should use SQL Join instead and then convert the result to Lookup in more complex way than I would having two tables returned and having only second table in Lookup instance?

Comment: Try showing us some sample data and end expected result

Comment: I think, a proper joining will solve your problem. But at first try to provide some sample data with expected result.

Comment: Added sample data and expected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

For `DataSet.Tables(0)`:

```
select ID, Name
from Table1
```

for `DataSet.Tables(1)`:

```
select Table2.ID, Table2.Value, Table2.Table1ID
from Table2 
    inner join Table1 on Table2.Table1ID = Table1.ID
```

Comment: I have that done this way actually : ) I was just hoping it could be done better. But I'll leave it this way then. Thanks a lot!